# Does jQuery has no selector which uses name attribute ? If yes why ? what can be possible work around?

Tags: jquery

I was following this tutorial about jQuery Selectors ---> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

It seems that there is no selector which uses name attribute of an element.. I have googled for the same but cant find any.

```
<input type ="text" name = "somename"/>
```

What is the reason?  What can be a workaround if i want to use name 'somename' only?

Comment: There is, but it's more verbose because there's no simple `name ` selector in CSS, and instead requires the attribute-equals notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `[name=your-name]` selector:

```
$('[name=your-name]').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, ***never ever use W3Schools for anything***. The information on that site is usually outdated, wrong or most likely both - [W3Fools.com](http://w3fools.com)

Also, there is even less reason to use it for jQuery when it has some of the best documentation of any framework - http://api.jquery.com.

To answer your question, you want to use the attribute selector:

```
$('input[name="somename"]')
```

More on the attribute selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Also: http://www.htmlandcsstutorial.com/blog/why-im-killing-w3schools-and-you-can-too

Answer (score 2):

W3Schools is a poor resource for anything; don't use it. The [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), on the other hand, is an excellent resource for reading up on the different selectors available.

No matter which tutorial on jQuery selectors you'll end up using, however, it'll be bound to cover attribute selectors, which is what you're interested in:

```
 $('input[name=somename]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **any** attribute:

```
$("element[attr_name='attr_value']");
```

So for your example:

```
$("input[attr_name='somename']");
```

Relevant docs - [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

`$("input[name=somename]");` would select your input

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("input[name=somename]");
```